# T-SQL Pivot duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure:

[image]

In this table the `DayOfWeek=2` is Monday and so on.

I am trying to use a pivot in order to get a result similar to this:

[image]

But for some reason in store 25 it generates duplicates with this query:

```sql
 SELECT p.Store, 
             CASE WHEN[2] is null THEN 0 ELSE LT END L,
             CASE WHEN[3] is null THEN 0 ELSE LT END M,
             CASE WHEN[4] is null THEN 0 ELSE LT END W,
             CASE WHEN[5] is null THEN 0 ELSE LT END J,
             CASE WHEN[6] is null THEN 0 ELSE LT END V          
             FROM(SELECT DISTINCT
             [DayOfWeek], Store, LT FROM replenishment.[Routes]) AS s 
                           PIVOT 
                           (MAX([DayOfWeek]) FOR[DayOfWeek] in  ([2], [3], [4], [5], [6])) as p 
                           WHERE p.Store=25
```

The result of this query is this:

[image]

How can I get the result without these duplicates?

Comment: Just curious; is it french day abbrevs? Mercredi is W?

Comment: Data has `text`, not as images will greatly help us help you. Personally, I always recommend a Cross Tab over the `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: And related to the question; are we supposed to subtract 2 form the store number to make 25 -> 23? Are we supposed to round the 4 down to the nearest odd number? You kinda need to explain how you expect us to derive the 23/3/3/3/3 output from raw data that is 25/3/3/3/4/3

Comment: It is a combination of abbreviations between days in Spanish and English. W is Wednesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using conditional aggregation:

```
 SELECT p.Store, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 2 THEN LT ELSE 0 END) as L,
        MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 3 THEN LT ELSE 0 END) as M,
        MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 4 THEN LT ELSE 0 END) as W,
        MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 5 THEN LT ELSE 0 END) as J,
        MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 6 THEN LT ELSE 0 END) as V
FROM replenishment.[Routes] r
WHERE p.Store = 25
GROUP BY p.Store;
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about it that way. It works for me, thank you very much!